# What router to get when upgrading from Linksys wrt54gl for use with dd-wrt/openwrt?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, dd-wrt, openwrt

I have been using the **wrt54gl** for a few years now, and would like to upgrade to a **802.11n**-capable router. 
It shouldn't be too expensive, and have a similar support in the hacking community as the wrt-series routers did. 
Firmware I would like to be able to run would include openwrt/dd-wrt and maybe Tomato. 
Maybe someone could make a few recommendadations?

Answer (score 1):

I, too, have been looking for a good 802.11n-capable router to put OpenWrt on, and [this Buffalo device](http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/buffalo/wzr-hp-g300h) is looking promising. Quoted from the OpenWrt wiki page I linked to:

> Status: Working (Backfire 10.03)
>
> As of July 2010, this router is available in the US for around $80. It has tons of flash and plenty of horsepower to handle a lot of bandwidth (at least 25Mbits bidirectionally based on some users' testing). It is easy to flash and hard to brick. Quite possibly the best gigabit-capable router that OpenWrt runs on at this point.

**Edit**

It turns out that the [Buffalo WZR-HP-G300NH](http://www.buffalo-technology.com/products/wireless/wireless-n-nfiniti/wzr-hp-g300nh-airstation-nfiniti-wireless-n-high-power-router/) comes with dd-wrt as the stock firmware. No need to wonder about compatibility, or worry about bricking.

Comment: this looks great, especially since it comes with a reasonable price-tag

Answer (score 0):

I have a [Netgear WNR3500L](http://www.netgear.co.uk/wnr3500l.php), which can run Tomato as well as DD-WRT and OpenWRT, and has 802.11n wireless (not dual band though - I don't think there are any that have that).

You can also look at the [Asus RT-N16](http://usa.asus.com/product.aspx?P_ID=WAa6AQFncrceRBEo), which has more memory.  I cannot remember the reason why I went for the Netgear instead.

I prefer Tomato as I could not get QoS working on DD-WRT.  Tomato also has just about evrything I would want and has nice bandwidth graphs.  The only things I miss is VLAN sections in the web-interface and Dual-SSID.

You can see on [this page](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Supported_Devices_802.11n#Linksys_.28Wireless_a.2Fb.2Fg.2Fn.29) that there are many Linksys models that have 802.11n and are supported by DD-WRT, but not Tomato.  I'm not sure if they have OpenWRT support.

Answer (score 0):

I got a [re certified Linksys WRT160NL](http://homestore.cisco.com/en-us/outlet/Routers/linksys-WRT160NL-RM-Wirelessn_stcVVproductId89001910VVcatId543809VVviewprod.htm) straight from Cisco, installed DD-WRT, and it's been rock-solid ever since.